# como escribir un WHERE en sentencia INSERT INTO en MySQL

Tags: mysql

quisiera saber como escribir un where en un insert into en mysql
intente con este que encontre en internet, pero solo me sale "column count doesnt match" en workbench

```
 #sentencia para agregar sistemas a unis solo si el sistema existe en la ciudad de la uni
INSERT INTO carrerasYsistemas (tipoSistema, carrera)
SELECT * FROM sistemasyciudades, sistemaUniversidad
WHERE sistemasyciudades.sistema = sistemaUniversidad.id;
```

lo que quiero es que en la tabla carrerasYsistemas, me agregue los datos en el parentecis, si es que una ciudad tiene un sistema

(me refiero a sistemas como sistemas escolares al estilo "escolarizado y sabatino")
(la tabla sistemasy ciudades es una tabla de muchos a muchos, donde contecta el id de la tabla ciudades y la tabla sistemas)

Comment: Si vas a insertar dos columnas, el `select` debe devolver dos columnas.

Answer (score 1):

deberías incluir las columnas que estás necesitando

```
INSERT INTO carrerasYsistemas (tipoSistema, carrera)
SELECT sistemaUniversidad.tipoSistema, sistemaUniversidad.carrera
FROM sistemasyciudades, sistemaUniversidad
WHERE sistemasyciudades.sistema = sistemaUniversidad.id;
```

Asumiendo que las columnas tipoSistema y carrera pertenecen a la tabla sistemaUniversidad.

Y como buena práctica te sugiero que uses INNER JOIN para ese tipo de cosas.

```
INSERT INTO carrerasYsistemas (tipoSistema, carrera)
SELECT T1.tipoSistema, T1.carrera
FROM sistemasyciudades T0
inner join sistemaUniversidad T1 on T1.id = T0.sistema
```

Saludos

Comment: pero y donde van los datos que voy a agregar? se supone que el insert into debe de llevar un "value("data")"

Comment: El "Value("data")" lo asumen las columnas que coloques en tu SELECT, recuerda el número y orden de columnas que vayas insertar deben ser las mismas que coloques en el SELECT.